Can Tesla shareholders sue Elon Musk for doing non-Tesla related things?
Tesla is a publicly-traded company, and Elon Musk is its CEO.
Presumably in such an arrangement, Musk is contractually obliged to dedicate his energies into expanding Tesla's business. However, he's doing lots of other things, like head SpaceX and campaign for Donald Trump in the upcoming US general election.
Can Tesla's shareholders sue Musk for not acting in their best interests?

Absent a very atypical shareholder agreement, Musk does not owe personal duties to other shareholders, and shareholders would not be able to sue Musk in a direct action.
However, as a director, Musk owes duties to the corporation. These duties are generally fiduciary, not contractual, although there may also be contractual duties.
If the corporation is unwilling to hold Musk accountable for actions that are in breach of his duties to the corporation, a shareholder or group of shareholders can commence what is known as a derivative action on behalf of the corporation.

How about things like sending Tesla resources to other Musk owned companies? Famously Musk sent over Tesla engineers to review Twitter code, and NVIDIA cards from Tesla to X-AI. Would that be misappropriation of company resources?

"Can sue" questions like this usually mean not to ask whether one can formally initiate a proceeding (literal reading of the question) but rather whether there is a potentially sound case. Is there one here?

@CharlesE.Grant I strongly suspect money was exchanged. Even within companies, it's common to have to "buy" things from yourself because one division is on government contracts with different accounting, is part of a joint venture, has foreign tax arrangements, etc.
